# Unabe to return my value after the api call - getting TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, json, api, object, flask

I am trying to fetch values from an api and return it using api call. When i try to call the api function , I am facing TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. My Code is below

```
import json
import requests
import datetime
import sys

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
port = '5000'

data = {
      "d": {
        "results": [{
          "timeAccount": "031799ce7bc344a2bb65e7f05cb08c49",
          "balance": "10.1388824",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }, {
          "timeAccount": "bc4fb4d44c3e413d8137a59d121c74b6",
          "balance": "25.347206",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }, {
          "timeAccount": "f12279ea0d34471581aff90ad71d3f83",
          "balance": "5.6249964",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }]
      }
    }


@app.route('/leave_balance')
def leave_balance():
    Balance = 0.0
    for res in data['d']["results"]:
        Balance = Balance + float(res("balance"))

    return jsonify(  
        {
        "conversation": {
            "memory": {
              "balance1" : Balance
             }
         }
        })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=port)
```

The json data i fetched using another api , i have added in the code as data. When i execute the leave balance function separately as normal program, it executing properly. But when i call as API I am facing this error

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-03-25 09:32:02,490] ERROR in app: Exception on /leave_balance [GET] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CAI-SF\datetime.py", line 101, in leave_balance
    Balance = Balance + float(res("balance"))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2020 09:32:02] "GET /leave_balance HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Please Help me with this

Comment: `res` is a dictionary, you should use the square bracket syntax for accessing it's keys - `Balance = Balance + float(res["balance"])`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment @Iain Shelvington, you have to use brackets on the python dictionary, but that is error prone, another way is to use `.get()` method which will not raise `KeyError` if such key does not exist.

For example, your code I would change to like this:

```py
import json
import requests
import datetime
import sys

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
port = '5003'

data = {
      "d": {
        "results": [{
          "timeAccount": "031799ce7bc344a2bb65e7f05cb08c49",
          "balance": "10.1388824",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }, {
          "timeAccount": "bc4fb4d44c3e413d8137a59d121c74b6",
          "balance": "25.347206",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }, {
          "timeAccount": "f12279ea0d34471581aff90ad71d3f83",
          "balance": "5.6249964",
          "timeAccountType": "SA_AL_DLY",
          "userId": "01000",
          "accountClosed": "false",
          "timeUnit": "DAYS"
        }]
      }
    }


@app.route('/leave_balance')
def leave_balance():
    Balance = 0.0
    for res in data['d']["results"]:
        b = res.get('balance', 0.0)
        Balance += float(b)

    return jsonify(  
        {
        "conversation": {
            "memory": {
              "balance1" : Balance
             }
         }
        })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=port)
```

Notice how I changed from:

```py
Balance = Balance + float(res("balance"))
```

To:

```py
b = res.get('balance', 0.0)
Balance += float(b)
```

So what happens in my example, is that first of all, I try to `get` the 'balance' from your dictionary like this `b = res.get('balance', 0.0)`, and if it doesn't exist, then I assign a `0.0` and no `KeyError` will be given.

Then I convert whatever `b` is to `float` and with `+=` I add new balance to `Balance` and thus resulting in UI:

[image: Example of web result]